# Having two 3D points (x,y,z) and multiple 2D points on a 2D image, convert the 2D points to the same reference as the 3D points

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, geometry, camera-calibration

I have a set of images of a moving object of interest (ball) from which I have some information:

[image: Release point]

I know the real-world starting point for the ball's path from the release from the pitcher's hand (Release Point or RP) in (x1, y1, z1) form where x1 and z1 are in feet and y1 is 0.

Secondly, I have the following info:

[image: Landing Point]

I also know the real-world endpoint for the ball's path at home plate (Landing Point or LP) in (x2, y2, z2) form where x2 and z2 are in feet and y2 is 60.5 feet, which is the distance from the Release Point to the Landing Point - neglecting the extension of the pitcher's arm, for the moment.

Through Object Detection I was able to get the (u,v) coordinates of the ball moving from the Release Point to the Landing Point, but that set of coordinates is relative to the image width and height (a standard 1280 x 720 image) and are not real world coordinates as the RP and LP ones.

[image: Ball Path]

I want to be able to convert, collect and plot all the (u, v) coordinates from the ball path in the 3D (x,y,z) plane for the real-world Release and Landing Points. Kind of like this but doesn't need to be over the image, just in a 3D plot:

[image: 3D reenactment]

I don't have any camera info (matrix, rotation, etc) but I guess I can interpret or find that from the image and the info I have (the RP and LP 3D coordinates).

I'm using Python so any pointers specific to it are welcome but I can translate to it as needed.

Thanks in advance for your time and ideas!

EDIT: The idea is to create something similar to these graphs with the info:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you don't have any Z data for the coordinates you got from the video feed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t.

Comment: then you need to get that. research commercial systems for this stuff. soccer uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goal-line_technology and I'm sure similar stuff is used for baseball, using only optical methods or including radio/radar localization

Comment: The (u,v) coordinates that you have do not describe a point in space, but a line (or ray, rather), starting at the center of you camera. Without depth information, the ball could be on any point on that line in each frame, making a reconstruction impossible.

Comment: I was thinking that knowing the initial and final 3d points, a reference frame could be used to “project” the 2D points. Seems that I was wrong, though.

Comment: if you knew that the ball moved in a plane positioned in any way in space, which isn't a given (curveballs), you could work with that of course.